# Write value to xml file, using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a PS script to read value from XML file:

```
PS D:\> $xml = [xml](Get-Content C:\Users\myuser\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml)
PS D:\> $VMFolder = $xml.VirtualBox.Global.SystemProperties.defaultMachineFolder
PS D:\> echo $VMFolder
D:\VirtualboxVMs
```

the example of xml file:

```
<VirtualBox xmlns="http://www.virtualbox.org/" version="1.12-windows">
  <Global>
    <SystemProperties defaultMachineFolder="D:\VirtualboxVMs" defaultHardDiskFormat="VDI" VRDEAuthLibrary="VBoxAuth" webServiceAuthLibrary="VBoxAuth" LogHistoryCount="3" exclusiveHwVirt="false"/>
  </Global>
</VirtualBox>
```

Can anyone give me an example, how to change value of defaultMachineFolder="D:\VirtualboxVMs" to "D:\newlocation" using PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
$xml.VirtualBox.Global.SystemProperties.defaultMachineFolder = "D:\VirtualboxVMs"
$xml.Save("C:\Users\myuser\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml")
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Unfortunately, original file in Unix (LF) encoding, and command save this file in Windows (CR LF) encoding. Is there any way to save this file with respect with encoding? Unfortunately,  $xml.Save("C:\Users\~~~\VirtualBox111.xml") -Encoding "UTF8" didn't work.

Comment: Powershell `[xml]` data type should be actually .Net `XmlDocument()` thus you should be able to call `$xml.Save()` on an [`XmlWriter()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter?view=netframework-4.7.2) which you can properly set up